# Is this function nowhere differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I was looking at the following function,
$$\displaystyle f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty {\sin(2^nx) \over 2^n}.$$
It is pretty obvious that $f$ is continous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$. But I can't figure out where it is differentiable. Differentiating term by term would lead me to believe it is differentiable nowhere but I'm not sure if I can do that.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: @LouisPan It doesn't seem to be a Weierstrass function since $ab=1$ . Does this mean it's differentiable everywhere and if yes is there any "easy" way to show it is?

Comment: The identity $f(x) = \sin(x) + f(2x)/2$ shows (a) $f$ is not differentiable at 0 (if it were we would have $f'(0) = 1 + f'(0)$), and hence (b) $f$ is not differentiable at any dyadic rational.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Using the same logic: $f'(2\pi/3)=\cos(2\pi/3)+\cos(4\pi/3) + f'(8\pi/3)=-1+f'(2\pi/3)$ so it cannot be differentiable at $2\pi/3$ either. I think the same argument carries over to any prime denominator $q$ and likely to any denominator. (I have not worked out the details yet.)

Comment: @bringradical "G. H. Hardy showed that the function of the above construction is nowhere differentiable with the assumptions 0 < a < 1, ab ≥ 1."

Comment: The derivative is $$\displaystyle f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {\cos(2^nx) }$$ which does not converge.

Comment: @Piquito generally, the derivative of an infinite summation is not the infinite summation of the derivatives.

Comment: @bringradical: Yes, as each teenager knows.

Comment: It's easy to see the derivative is given by the (possibly nonexistent) limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(2^n h)}{2^n h}\cos(2^nx)$. Taking $h = 2^{-N}$ seems nice, though doesn't immediately finish the problem. In any event, didn't @Wojowu's comment answer the question? [Here](https://moam.info/hardy-gh-weierstrasss-nondifferentiable-function-trans-amer-_5a0dc8541723dd4f3ab098cc.html) is a link to the relevant paper.

Comment: [Here is your answer](http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Riemann_function_is_almost_nowhere_differentiable) with the “Riemann function” in the Special Functions wiki.

Comment: If you compute the derivative as a limit and consider the increments $h=2^{-m}\pi$, you get a series that does not converge to zero at the numerator.

Comment: This may help: on pp. 114-118 and p. 174 (Problem 8) in Stein&Shakarchi "Fourier Analysis" $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{n\alpha}e^{i2^n x}$ ($0 < \alpha <1$) is shown  to be nowhere differentiable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect $f$ is differentiable nowhere, because its derivative is "trying" to be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(2^n x)$, which converges nowhere. Below I show that $f$ is differentiable *almost* nowhere.

**Claim 1:** If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{n=0}^N \cos(2^n x)$ is bounded.

Proof: There is a uniform estimate of the form
$$\frac{\sin(x) - \sin(y)}{x - y} = \cos(x) + O(|x-y|).$$
Plugging this into the definition of $f$ and truncating the sum gives $$\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} = \sum_{n=0}^N \cos(2^n x) + O(2^N |x-y|+ 2^{-N} |x-y|^{-1}).$$
Now pick $y$ so that $|x-y| = 2^{-N}$. It follows that
$$\sum_{n=0}^N \cos(2^n x) = \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} + O(1) = f'(x) + O(1)$$
if $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

**Claim 2:** For almost all $x$ (in the sense of either measure or category), the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{n=0}^N \cos(2^n x)$ is not bounded.

Proof: Consider the binary expansion of $x / (2 \pi)$. Almost surely there will be a long stretch of zeros somewhere. That means there is some $n$ such that $2^n x \approx 0$ mod $2 \pi$, so the partial sums cannot be bounded.

There are some $x$ for which the partial sums $\sum_{n=0}^N \cos(2^n x)$ are bounded, e.g., $x = 2\pi / q$ for any proper prime power $q$ such that $2$ is a primitive root (e.g., $q = 9$). I still doubt that $f$ is differentiable at these points.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I'm not sure I deserve the green tick, just almost all of it.

Answer (score 6):

I apologize because I am force to write it on phone. I hope it will be not to hard to read.

In fact, there is a powerful theorem that give conditions for which a "lacunary trigonometric serie" is nowhere differenriable. The proof can be found in the french book, Analyse pour l'agrégation, Zuily-Quéffelec.

Let $a_n$, be a complex sequence with $\sum |a_n| < \infty$. Let $b_n$ be a real sequence. Define $d_n = dist(b_n, (b_k)_{k \neq n}) $. We suppose that $d_n>0$ and $d_n \to \infty$.
Then, if $f(x) = \sum a_n e^{i b_n t} $ is differentiable at one point (at least), then $a_n d_n \to 0$.

By contradiction, it show that the function of this question is nowhere differentiable ($a_n = 1/2^n$ or $- i/2^n$ and $b_n = 2^n$ or $-2^n$, depending of the parity of n. Thus $a_n d_n = 1/2$).

The proof of the theorem goes as follow. Let $\phi$ be a Schwarz function with $\hat{\phi}(0)=1$ and with support of $\hat{\phi} $ included in $[-1,1]$ (we can construct it by taking the Fourier transfort of the a test function with support included in $[-1,1]$).
By Fubini theorem :

$a_n = \int f(x/d_n) \phi(x) e^{-i b_n/d_n x} dx$
(just expand f, intervert sum and integral and use the fact that the support of $\hat{\phi}$ is included in $[-1,1] $.

The next step is to handle the case where f is differentiable at 0 with $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.
Then by considering "small x" (main argument : differentiability at 0) and "big x" (main argument : $\sum |a_n| < \infty$) we can prove that for all x :
$|f(x)| \leq C| x|$
with $C > 0$

The can now easily conclude, in that particular case, using the expression of $a_n$, the previous estimate of $f$ and the fact that $\phi$ is Schwarz, that $a_n d_n \to 0$ (Lebesgue theorem can be applied).

For the general case, if f is differentiable at $x_0$, we consider $g(x) = f(x + x_0) + a e^{i b_1 x} + b e^{ i b_2 x}$ with $a, b$ chosen such that $g$ satisfies the particular case above. Thus $g$ is nowhere differentiable, and thus also $f$.

Comment: Problem aside, how could you just write all those things on the phone?! wow

Comment: I am hiking for 3 month now, without computer, I was obliged to get used to it aha

Comment: I use "text replacement" on my phone's keyboard, so that when I type "bmat", my phone types ```\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}```, when I type "iint", my phone types ```\int_{  }^{  }```, when I type "rrn", my phone types ```\mathbb{R}^{n}```, etc.